# SVG in Flex Box Disappears in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I'm using an svg inside a flex box to center a letter inside of a div. The letter should have a maximum size, but otherwise should scale itself down if the div is too small. (I do not have control over the size of the div.)

However, for some reason it works as I expect in Firefox, but the element completely disappears in Chrome(ium). I don't know if the bug is mine, or in either Firefox or Chrome. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Here's the complete file:

```
<html><body>
    <div style="width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#cfc; border: solid 1px black; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
        <svg style="display:block; font-family:sans; background-color:#ffc; max-width:200px;" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
            <text style="font-size:10px;" x="50%" y="60%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">X</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind--adding a "width:100%" to the SVG fixed it. Still, it's an odd difference between Firefox and Chrome, that I'm sure is going to cause others headaches.

Answer (score 1):

change `max-width` to `width`

```html
<div style="width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#cfc; border: solid 1px black; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
        <svg style="display:block; font-family:sans; background-color:#ffc; width:200px;" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
            <text style="font-size:10px;" x="50%" y="60%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">X</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/dc9uyt12/5/

Comment: That works, but it removes the max-width which was needed. Thanks, though.